# CloseableHttpClient and How to use it from connection pool?

Tags: java, httpclient, connection-pooling, closeablehttpresponse

I have a creating a connectionManager for the pool as this -->>

```
    public static PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager getCm() {
        return cm;
    }

    public static void setCm(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm) {
        ClassName.cm = cm;
    }

public static PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager createPool()
        {
            System.out.println("Generating new connection pool");
            setCm( new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager());   
            getCm().setMaxTotal(10);
            getCm().setDefaultMaxPerRoute(5);
            return getCm();
        }
```

I am creating an instance of CloseableHttpClient using this -->>

```
    public static CloseableHttpClient createConnection(){
            if(getCm()!=null)
                return  HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(getCm()).setConnectionManagerShared(true).setDefaultRequestConfig(getConfig()).build();
            else
                return HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(createPool()).setConnectionManagerShared(true).setDefaultRequestConfig(getConfig()).build();
        }
```

But here each time I am creating an instance of CloseableHttpClient using the PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager. I am confused if this is the correct way or not?

In the Class where I make a HTTP call, I am doing it in this way--->>

```
private static CloseableHttpClient client;   //class level variable. static or final? Which one to prefer? I want this to handle more than 50 concurrent request

Inside My method--->>

client = createConnection();

String endPoint = //someendpoint 
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(endPoint);
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Accept-API-Version", "resource=2.0, protocol=1.0");


CloseableHttpResponse response1 = null;
        try{
             response1 =  client.execute(httpPost);
                String responseString;
                int statusCode;
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response1.getEntity());
         //doing something useful
         }catch(){
          
          } finally(){           //Another big question comes here. How to close and what should I close?
                                 /Just to be on the safe side, I am closing everything
           httpPost.releaseConnection();
           if(response1!= null)
                        response1.close();
           if (client != null)
                        client.close();
        

         }
```

Please suggest the best way or the alternative? Also I am a newbie and doing this to learn so forgive and correct me If I made any mistake.